# Android setImageResource on imageButton

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I wrote a memory game app and I have a function that called "OnImageButtonClick" that I inserted in each imageButton's onClick attribute in the layout.
When you click the image it supposed to change its image but what realy happens is that only after the function ends the image actually changes.

```
public void onImageButtonClick(View v) throws InterruptedException {
    int cardIndex = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
    ImageButton card = (ImageButton)v;
    Resources resources = this.getResources();
    int imageId = resources.getIdentifier(imageArr[cardIndex-1], "drawable", this.getPackageName());
    card.setImageResource(imageId);


    if(isFirst) {
        pickedCards[0] = card;
    }
    else {
        pickedCards[1] = card;
    }

    PickCard();
}

public void PickCard() throws InterruptedException{
    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't play music", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        if(!isFirst) {
            if (pickedCards[0].getBackground() == pickedCards[1].getBackground()){
                Points++;
            }
            else {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                pickedCards[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.card);
                pickedCards[1].setImageResource(R.drawable.card);
            }
        }

        isFirst = !isFirst;
    }
```

the problem is that PickCard happens before the image actually changes.

Comment: sounds a´like a heavy memory using task. What does PickCard() do?

Comment: look at my edit @Opiatefuchs

Comment: Here is an example of what I said: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15709457

Comment: The Asynctask that Alberto suggested, first executes the set of image and then your PickCard() method. And what you are doing here `pickedCards[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.card);`? If this is the same button, than it´s just logical that the buttons image is set later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, is a bit complex, but may work:

Create a Asynctask and execute first method (change the image resource) and after the first method is executed then onPostExecute method call PickCard().

Here is some documentation to how to do this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

---

```
public class ImgBtnClick extends AsyncTask<ImageButton, Void, Void> {


public ImgBtnClick (Context contexts) {
    context = contexts;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
     //Insert Here the code to change the Image resource
    /*
int cardIndex = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
ImageButton card = (ImageButton)v;
Resources resources = this.getResources();
int imageId = resources.getIdentifier(imageArr[cardIndex-1], "drawable", this.getPackageName());
card.setImageResource(imageId);


if(isFirst) {
    pickedCards[0] = card;
}
else {
    pickedCards[1] = card;
}
    */
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
    PickCard()
  }

}
```

Comment: But why would I need async for this? It doesnt need to be that difficult

Comment: Because this can solve your problem securely, It does what you need :)
I hope this solved your problem :D